# listings package's \lstlistoflistings command generates an error

Tags: errors, listings, amsart

Processing the following .tex file with LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={An example}]
Hello, world!
\end{lstlisting}

\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\@dottedtocline ... \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep 
                                                  mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep...l.1 ...lstlisting}{\numberline {1}An Example}{1}

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name. If this message occurs when a LaTeX command is being processed,
the command is probably in the wrong place---for example, the error
can be produced by an \item command that's not inside a list-making
environment. The error can also be caused by a missing \documentclass
command.
```

When the `\lstlistoflistings` line is commented out, the file compiles successfully.

Comment: Looks like some leftovers from the previous latex runs. Remove all the generated auxiliary files and run latex again.

Comment: Though looks like `\lstlistoflistings` uses some macros which aren't defined in the `amsart` document class. If you define `\@dotsep` (as `\def\@dotsep{4.5}` for example) then it starts working again.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: You were right about removing the generated auxiliary files, however a slightly changed .tex file (see my changed post above) results in a similar error even when the auxiliary files are removed.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Adding `\def\@dostep{4.5}` before the `\begin{document}` line doesn't help.

Comment: `\@dotsep`, not `\@dostep`. This works: `\makeatletter \def\@dotsep{4.5} \makeatother`

Comment: @SergeiGolovan: Yes! This works indeed. Thank you. Could you please explain to me what this line does? Why does it solve the problem?

Comment: It's distance between two consecutive dots in a TOC line. Apparently it isn't defined in answer. Might be because it doesn't use dotted TOCs.

Comment: @SergeiGolovan -- you've got the right answer.  please post it as an answer.  (you can add the note that toc lines in `amsart` are not dotted by default.)

Comment: @SergeiGolovan would you care to expand your comment in order for this question to have an answer? I think it could be quite an interesting one

Comment: @SergeiGolovan -- your comment solved the problem, but the explanation in an answer could help someone else.  please provide an answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This seems to be an issue with a few packages. For example, the same problem arises with the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [subcaption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) packages. Perhaps the AMS document classes should define `\@dotsep`?

Comment: @Andrew -- While that seems a reasonable suggestion, the AMS style doesn't include dots.  I'll send in the suggestion, but have my doubts that it will be accepted.