# \listoftheorems from thmtools not working in amsart

Tags: amsart, thmtools

I am trying to use the command \listoftheorems from the package thmtools in a document with class amsart. I am compiling through pdflatex. The example

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}[From somewhere]\label{thm1} A theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \listoftheorems

\end{document}
```

generates the following error in the log file (I have copy-pasted what I think is the relevant part).

```
(test2.loe
! Undefined control sequence.
\@dottedtocline ... \hbox {$\m@th \mkern \@dotsep 
                                                  mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep...
l.1 ...eorem\thmtformatoptarg {From somewhere}}{1}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   m
l.1 ...eorem\thmtformatoptarg {From somewhere}}{1}
                                                  %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Undefined control sequence.
\@dottedtocline ...sep mu\hbox {.}\mkern \@dotsep 
                                                  mu$}\hfill \nobreak \hb@xt...
l.1 ...eorem\thmtformatoptarg {From somewhere}}{1}
                                                  %
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   m
l.1 ...eorem\thmtformatoptarg {From somewhere}}{1}
                                                  %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

)
\tf@loe=\write3
\openout3 = `test2.loe'.
```

It is worth noting two things:

1. If I compile the MWE above with the command "\listoftheorems" commented out, then there is no error, and if I *then* uncomment the \listoftheorems back in, then the pdf seems to be correctly output, also with hyperlinks working, *but the compiler is still giving me the error message*.
2. If I replace the documentclass back with article, for example, then there is no issue. But I need to get it working with amsart.

Please help!

Comment: Only the first error is useful here; all the others are a consequence of the first, and essentially meaningless.  Essentially, the problem is that the definition of lines for the LOT conflicts with that defined for regular contents lines in `amsart`.  (Contents lines in `amsart` do not connect text and page number with dots; the lines with `thmtools` are more like the lines defined for `article`.)  I may or may not be able to define a patch, but the relevant code is in the module `thm-listof.sty`, in case someone else gets to it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your appraisal! Unfortunately I am not well-versed enough in coding of tex to fix the issue myself at this point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is a style incompatibility between `amsart` (in fact, all the AMS document classes) and several packages that implement "lists of".  The AMS class style for tables of and lists of doesn't use dots between a heading and the associated page number, while the basic LaTeX classes and a number of packages do.  (This is also the subject of other questions, such as [listings package's `\lstlistoflistings` command generates an error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371072), but I haven't found an answer to link this to as a duplicate.)

It's quite easy to provide a fix that will get rid of the error, at the cost of having inconsistent style between different lists of.  The following example does just that.  Making the styles of these lists of parallel is more complicated, and won't be addressed here.

The definition of `\@dotsep` is copied from `article.cls` and is defined here with `\providecommand` so that if another package loaded earlier defines it, it won't be overwritten.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\makeatother

\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{theorem}[From somewhere]\label{thm1} A theorem.
    \end{theorem}

    \listoftheorems

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer; it is working for me now!

Comment: Hello barbara, currently `thmtools` 0.72 uses `\ifdefined\@tocline` to test whether it is used with an AMS class. Is it safe enough?

Answer (score 1):

I've added the required changes to `thmtools` and released **v0.72 2020/08/01**. Now `\listoftheorems` used in AMS classes will have styles similar to list of tables and figures. The related changes can be seen in this [commit](https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/commit/c8b00fc308b3f9e52823578b92591726bc90aea7).

A full example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{thmtools} 
\declaretheorem{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numbered=no]{definition}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\listoftheorems
\listoftheorems[title={List of Theorems (number swapped)}, swapnumber]

\section{title}
\subsection{title}
\begin{figure}[b]
  content
  \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}[Numbered]
  A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}[Unnumbered]
  A definition.
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]